# Volley With Gson Sync Request

Tags: android, request, synchronization, android-volley

I have a volley request using Gson but i want to populate an spinner with the volley response. But it's assync.

```
EstadoRequestHelper.statesRequest(Request.Method.GET, EndpointURL.GET_ESTADO, null, new Response.Listener<Estado[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Estado[] response) {
            ArrayList<Estado> estadoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            Estado estado = new Estado();
            estado.setId(0);
            estado.setDescricao("Selecione um estado");

            estadoArrayList.add(estado);
            estadoArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(response));

            estadoAdapter = new EstadoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, estadoArrayList);
            spn_estado.setAdapter(estadoAdapter);

            //If i get the spn_estado selection here, 
            //it works, but i dont want to get it here...

            progressDialogEstado.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialogEstado.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERRO ESTADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

If i populate the spn_estado into the request, it comes... But i dont want to populate it into the request...

```
private void veferyUser() {
    usuario = UsuarioSingleton.getInstance().getUsuario();

    if (usuario == null) {
        et_telefone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_celular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_logradouro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_numero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_complemento.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_bairro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spn_cidade.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spn_estado.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        et_nome.setText(usuario.getNome() != null ? usuario.getNome() : "");
        et_cpf.setText(usuario.getCpf() != null ? usuario.getCpf() : "");
        et_email.setText(usuario.getEmail() != null ? usuario.getEmail() : "");
        et_telefone.setText(usuario.getTelefone() != null ? usuario.getTelefone() : "");
        et_celular.setText(usuario.getCelular() != null ? usuario.getCelular() : "");

        progressDialogEstado = Util.ProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Carregando Estados", getString(R.string.prompt_aguarde));
        requestEstados();

        if (usuario.getEndereco() != null) {
            et_logradouro.setText(usuario.getEndereco().getLogradouro() != null ? usuario.getEndereco().getComplemento() : "");
            et_numero.setText(String.valueOf(usuario.getEndereco().getNumero()));
            et_complemento.setText(usuario.getEndereco().getComplemento() != null ? usuario.getEndereco().getComplemento() : "");
            et_bairro.setText(usuario.getEndereco().getBairro() != null ? usuario.getEndereco().getBairro() : "");

            if (usuario.getEndereco().getCidade() != null) {
                spn_cidade.setSelection(usuario.getEndereco().getCidade().getId(), false);
                if (usuario.getEndereco().getCidade().getEstado() != null) {
                 //I want to populate it here.
                 spn_estado.setSelection(usuario.getEndereco().getCidade().getEstado().getId(), false);
                }
            }
        }

        btn_registrar.setText(R.string.action_edit);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do u want to achieve exactly? why async is an issue ?

Comment: because when reach the other method, the adapter comes null... than i can't get the position for my spn_estado spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use RequestFuture:

```
    RequestFuture<Estado[]> future = RequestFuture.newFuture(); 
EstadoRequestHelper.statesRequest(Request.Method.GET, EndpointURL.GET_ESTADO, null, future, future);
```

after adding the request to the queue, do:

```
    try {
        Estado[] response = future.get();
ArrayList<Estado> estadoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                Estado estado = new Estado();
                estado.setId(0);
                estado.setDescricao("Selecione um estado");

                estadoArrayList.add(estado);
                estadoArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(response));

                estadoAdapter = new EstadoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, estadoArrayList);
                spn_estado.setAdapter(estadoAdapter);

                //If i get the spn_estado selection here, 
                //it works, but i dont want to get it here...

                progressDialogEstado.dismiss();

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handle the interrupted error
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        progressDialogEstado.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERRO ESTADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

This is a blocking call and will return after the call or error is received

Note that while this answers your question a better way to handle your issue is to make sure your other part of the code (where the adapter is checked for example) can handle async behaviour.

Comment: Didn't work open those brackets... future don't accept it. I'll update my question for you undestand what happening... Why i want to use sync request...

Comment: what do you mean by 'Didn't work open those brackets... future don't accept it' ?

Comment: Android Studio says me to use RequestFuture<Estado[]> future = RequestFuture.newFuture(); Sorry, I'm new in android... :(

Comment: Thx brow! Worked like a charm :)